# Extract mobile menu from responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

i'm working with this menu: http://jsfiddle.net/4Q29m/ But i want to extract only the mobile menu, i want to `display` only the mobile menu, not the menu for PC and large resolutions.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
But if you want only the mobile part of that menu this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/XH9GH/1/).
If you want the menu extends itself over all sceen you have to remove one selector after my comment in css code (see fiddle page).
This is just a simple example, I hope it can help you.
in javascript part i have change the adaptMenu function:

```
function adaptMenu() {
    $('.rmm').each(function() {
            var $width = $(this).css('max-width');
            $width = $width.replace('px', ''); 
                $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
        });

}
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.